# Why does Deno.run not work for some commands?

Tags: deno

When I run `code .` in my MacOS terminal it opens VSCode in the current folder.

However nothing happens when I run `deno run --allow-run file.ts` where file.ts is the following:

```
Deno.run({ cmd: ["code", "."] });
```

---

I've looked at the Deno.run documentation and cannot find anything as to why this doesn't work.

Tests I've run:

- `Deno.run({ cmd: ["which", "code"] });` outputs `/usr/local/bin/code` (same as terminal).
- `Deno.run({ cmd: ["type", "code"] });` outputs nothing. The terminal outputs `code is /usr/local/bin/code`!

How do I start working out why some commands work (`which`) and others don't (`code` and `type`)?

Comment: Do you get error messages?

Comment: No error messages. Deno exits fine with code 0.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your process is ending before the new subprocess command completes causing the subprocess to be interrupted/killed before completion.

You can await the `output()` or `status()` to avoid this:

```js
await Deno.run({ cmd: ["code", "."] }).status();
```

Comment: Makes perfect sense, thanks.